# Regex to remove external links with out text

Tags: regex

I've situation where I've the following content like this

```
This is a <a href="https://www.test.com">test1</a>. This is <a href="/node/1">test2</a>. This is <a href="https://nct.com">test3</a>. This is a <a href="www.test.com">test4</a>. This is a <a href="http://test.com">test5</a>.
```

nct.com is my website. I don't want to remove that link and text wrapped inside a tag. So is /node/1.

The output I'm expecting is

```
This is a test1. This is <a href="/node/1">test2</a>. This is <a href="https://nct.com">test3</a>. This is a test4. This is a test5.
```

Where as for external websites like test.com, I would like a tag contents without removing the text wrapped inside a tag.

Th regex I'm using is

```
#<a [^>]*\bhref=(['"])http.?://((?<!mywebsite)[^'"])+\1 *.*?</a>#i
```

This will remove the a tag content as well as the text inside the a tag.

Comment: Do you want nct.com and /node/1 hardcoded in the regex or just urls without http(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I created a regex that does what i think you need:

```
/<a [^>]*\bhref=(['"])((https?:\/\/|www.)((?!nct\.com).)(.*?))['"]*\b<\/a>/
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/OqBsEl/7)

Comment: The regex is not working for me. I've updated the question, could you please help me with it.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra I updated the regex (and test url), it's not the cleanest one but matches all invalid url's from your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = 'This is a <a href="https://www.test.com">test1</a>. This is <a href="/node/1">test2</a>. This is <a href="https://nct.com">test3</a>. This is a <a href="www.test.com">test4</a>. This is a <a href="http://test.com">test5</a>.'
final_list = [re.findall("^[a-zA-Z\s]+", i)[0]+re.findall('com">(.*?)</a>', i)[0] if "nct.com" not in i and "node" not in i else i for i in re.split("\.\s(?=This)", s)]
```

Output:

```
['This is a test1', 'This is <a href="/node/1">test2</a>', 'This is <a href="https://nct.com">test3</a>', 'This is a test4', 'This is a test5']
```